# How to change progress bar style of uploadify

Tags: css, progress-bar, uploadify

How can I change the CSS style of progress upload bars and backgrounds in uploadify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried messing with the styles? Like so:

```
.uploadifyProgressBar {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```